# Blur and un-Blur selected portion of image on finger touch in Android

Tags: android, graphics, android-canvas, android-imageview, android-image

I have searched the some example but found solutions like blur full image, update radius on seekbar change. I want to blur and un-blur selected region of the image, that could be circle or rectangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try https://developers.aviary.com/docs/android

for your best performance